# Disabling Ocp-Apim-Trace in the Azure API Management Services

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to disable `Ocp-Apim-Trace` in the Azure API Management Services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to disable tracing funtionality, not sending this header will disable tracing collection for one request only. But do know, that only admin users are capable of collecting traces, if this header is supplied along with subscription key that does not belong to admin account (or no subscription key at all) no traces will be collected. The idea here is that traces may expose information service owner may not be willing to share with developers.

Answer (score 1):

As well as doing what Vitaliy suggests, you could additionally strip the `Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location` header from the response in the outbound and error sections as insurance.